# is this class a valueobject or not?

Tags: validation, domain-driven-design

I have defined classes like Email,Url,Alphabet,Number and ... just to centralize the validation logic needed for each of these objects , like :

```
public class Email
{
    private string value;
    private bool isValid;

    const string RegexPattern = @"^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$";


        public Email(string address, int minLength = 8, int maxLength = 50)
        {
            value = address;

            isValid = Validator.IsValid(address,RegexPattern,minLength,maxLength);
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get
            {
                return value;
            }
        }

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                return isValid;
            }
        }


}
```

can this be called a value object ?if not what it lacks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is one I would expect for a value object. It is immutable (though you may want to add `readonly` modifiers on the fields) and doesn't seem to have its own identity.

You need to consider whether it is indeed a value object depending on the domain - that's how you decide whether this should be a value object or not.

Comment: may you explain a bit more about the phrase "depending on the domain" ?

Comment: @mohsen.d - If you are doing DDD, then whether an entity is a value object or an aggregate root depends on the domain of discourse. I am talking about the _conceptual_ role of the entity, not your specific implementation.

Comment: @Oded oded can you go please to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17756/room-for-royi-namir-and-oded ?